# Count the amount of NaNs in each group

Tags: python, pandas

In this dataframe, I'm trying to count how many NaN's there are for each color within the `color` column.

This is what the sample data looks like. In reality, there's 100k rows.

```py
   color     value  
0  blue      10 
1  blue      NaN  
2  red       NaN
3  red       NaN
4  red       8
5  red       NaN
6  yellow    2
```

I'd like the output to look like this:

```py
   color     count  
0  blue      1 
1  red       3
2  yellow    0
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`DataFrame.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html), [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the column `color` and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to add up all `True` rows in each group:

```
df.value.isna().groupby(df.color).sum().reset_index()

    color  value
0    blue    1.0
1     red    3.0
2  yellow    0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use isna().sum()

```
df.groupby('color').value.apply(lambda x: x.isna().sum())

color
blue      1
red       3
yellow    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you may use agg() and isnull() or isna() as follows:

```
df.groupby('color').agg({'value': lambda x: x.isnull().sum()}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

A usage from `size` and `count`

```
g=df.groupby('color')['value']
g.size()-g.count()
Out[115]: 
color
blue      1
red       3
yellow    0
Name: value, dtype: int64
```